# Ansible conditional

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, ansible

My goal is to find a way to combine the two statements below but am coming up short.  For this instance, I have Package1 and Package2 that are being installed regardless of rhel version.  However, Package3 will be a different package depending on OS version.  Seems redundant and there should be a way to combine, but is this the best way to go about it? Any feedback is definitely welcome.

```
  - name: Install Packages
    yum:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: latest
    loop:
      - package1
      - package2
      - package3A (Only for RHEL8 versions)
    when: "{{ ansible_distribution_version }} >= 8.0"

  - name: Install Packages
    yum:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: latest
    loop:
      - package1
      - package2
      - package3B (Only for RHEL7 versions)
    when: "{{ ansible_distribution_version }} < 8.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare the variables

a) Use [*Jinja*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#) template and test [*version*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions)

```yaml
    packages:
      - package1
      - package2
      - "{{ package3 }}"
    package3: >-
      {%- if ansible_distribution_version is version('8.0', '>=') -%}
      package3A
      {%- elif ansible_distribution_version is version('8.0', '<') -%}
      package3B
      {%- endif -%}
```

b) Put the options into a dictionary and use the variable *ansible_distribution_major_version*

```yaml
    packages:
      - package1
      - package2
      - "{{ package3[ansible_distribution_major_version|int]|
            default(package3.default) }}"
    package3:
      default: package3A
      7: package3B
      6: package3B
      5: package3B
```

2. Install the packages from the list

```yaml
- name: Install Packages
    yum:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: latest
    loop: "{{ packages }}"
```

Comment: This looks like a good answer, but I don't have the experience with the code in this manner. Should be pretty easy to test tho.

Comment: I added a simpler option. HTH.